# Building .o file using makefile, clarification needed

Tags: makefile

My makefile contains the following lines

```
 11 SRC := $(shell echo src/*.cpp)
 12 SRC += $(shell echo $(TEST_ROOT)/*.cpp)
 13 
 14 OBJECTS = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

 22 # [debug] target
 23 $(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
 24   $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET)
 25 
 26 # [debug] .o
 27 $(OBJECTS): $(SRC)
 28   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) -c $(SRC) $(OBJECTS)
```

Which fails because ... well the following evidently is not a way to do it

```
g++ -pedantic -Wall -Werror -O0 -g -Wno-format -DUSE_MEASURE -c src/Timer.cpp test/TimerTest.cpp src/Timer.o test/TimerTest.o
```

How should i modify line #28 to produce .o from all my sources please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) -c $< $@
```

This rule will build one object file, and Make will call it once for each object that the other rule needs. You can write a rule that will build all object files in one pass, but there's no advantage to that.

**EDIT:**

Suppose `SRC` is `src/foo.cpp src/bar.cpp testroot/baz.cpp`,

so `OBJECTS` is `src/foo.o src/bar.o testroot/baz.o`

We could have a separate rule for each:

```
src/foo.o : src/foo.cpp
    ...

src/bar.o : src/bar.cpp
    ...

testroot/baz.o : testroot/baz.cpp
    ...
```

But that's redundant (since the commands are very similar) and inconvenient (since we don't want to add/remove rules whenever we add/remove targets). So we use a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
%.o : %.cpp
    ...
```

Now when Make wants to build `src/foo.o`, it sees that the target matches the pattern `%.o`, the stem (corresponding to `%`) is `src/foo`, and the corresponding prereq, `src/foo.cpp` exists, so it uses this rule.

But we have a variable `OBJECTS` that lists the targets we want to build with this rule, so we can restrict it to a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern), which looks about the same but has some advantages we need not get into here:

```
$(OBJECTS) : %.o : %.cpp
    ...
```

Now for the `...` part. The command tells the compiler to scan the prereq (`src/foo.cpp`) and build the target (`src/foo.o`), so we must refer to those things in the command. [Automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) help with that; `$@` is the name of the target, and `$<` is the name of the first (and in this case the only) prerequisite:

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) -c $< $@
```

Comment: Beta - Thank you so very much. A very nice and informative answer. If i could I would ++ you twice!

Comment: Quick question, using the scenario you described, how can i build both  debug and release versions of the code? Setting up `$(D_OBJECTS) : %.o: %.cpp` and `$(R_OBJECTS) : %.o: %.cpp` does not work

Comment: @James: you have some decisions to make first. You can't very well have two versions of `foo.o` in the same directory, so you can a) have separate `debug/` and `release/` directories for the objects (my favorite approach), b) name them `foo_debug.o` and `foo_release.o`, or c) have only one version of `foo.o` extant at a time, with some cleverness to help Make remember which one it is.